# HikariCP with Oracle com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, hikaricp, callable-statement

I using `Hikari Pool` and `OracleCallableStatement`:

My datasource:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
      <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${my.oracle.url}"/>
      <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"/>
      <property name="username" value="${my.oracle.user}"/>
      <property name="password" value="${my.oracle.password}"/>
</bean>
```

And I try make a request to `Oracle`:
 public List getProducts(int numbersMonths, Long initServiceId,

```
List<Long> serviceIds) throws SQLException {
        Connection cnn = null;
        OracleCallableStatement stm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        List<ProductLink> res = new ArrayList<>();
        final String sql = sqlCust(sqlProducts);
        try {
            cnn = custDataSource.getConnection();
            stm = (OracleCallableStatement) cnn.prepareCall(sql);
            stm.setPlsqlIndexTable(1, serviceIds.toArray(), serviceIds.size(), serviceIds.size(), OracleTypes.BIGINT, 0);
            stm.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            stm.setLong(3, initServiceId);
            stm.setInt(4, numbersMonths);
            stm.execute();
            rs = stm.getCursor(2);
            // do stuff
} catch (SQLException ex) {
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(cnn, stm, rs);
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(cnn, stm, rs);
        }
```

But I have error om this line: `stm = (OracleCallableStatement) cnn.prepareCall(sql);`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement
```

Also I have a error:

```
Failed to create instance of driver class oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource, trying jdbcUrl resolution
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver
```

on this line: `cnn = custDataSource.getConnection();`

What is wrong? Why I getting this errors?

Comment: the second error message (classcastexception) is due to a mis-configured driver class name: Please use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` instead of `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource` (it is not/an outdated driver class name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, since you are using a connection pool, the `CallableStatement` implementation is not from the driver, but from that connection pool instead.

Either you should find a way to access the *core* implementation (which I think is risky), or you should try to use the `CallableStatement` only, and not depend on Oracle implementation.

Comment: But, `pool` don't have method `setPlsqlIndexTable `

Comment: I see. Well, in that case, you should unwrap your CallableStatement for that implementation. That may work.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Wrapper.html#unwrap(java.lang.Class)

Try `cnn.prepareCall(sql).unwrap(OracleCallableStatement.class)`

Comment: How true this is? Will there be a drop in performance from using the pool because of this?

Comment: This is very true, dude. You see, the `unwrap` method is an official method for the Statement interface (from `java.sql`), which is a super interface for `CallableStatement`. If you look the Hikari CP's implementation, you will find out there is a recursion to find if the inner instance can be cast to the required interface. Meaning you should not have problem using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) instead

> The interface used to execute SQL stored procedures. The JDBC API provides a stored procedure SQL escape syntax that allows stored procedures to be called in a standard way for all RDBMSs.

This is used by [prepareCall](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall(java.lang.String)) method

> Creates a CallableStatement object

Comment: How can I use CallableStatement if it doesn't have a method `setPlsqlIndexTable`

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the line

```
            stm = (OracleCallableStatement) cnn.prepareCall(sql);
```

with

```
            stm = cnn.prepareCall(sql).unwrap(OracleCallableStatement.class);
```

Comment: How true this is? Will there be a drop in performance from using the pool because of this?